# How to get 5V from 12V with server power supply unit?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

My PSU has a connector for a GPU. It has +12 V, +3.3 V  and GND pins (according to voltmeter).

I need to connect cages with HDDs to this connector. A HDD requires +12 V and **+5V**. Because the PSU doesn't provide +5V I'm going to convert either +12 V or +3.3 V to +5 V.

Usually a PSU specifies a maximum current for a given line (say 20 A for +5 V or 40 A for 12 V). The specifications for my PSU have no information about such limits for 3.3 V or 12 V; it only says that it's possible to connect a 300 W GPU to aforementioned PSU connector. I think that the +12bV line allows more current than the 3.3 V line.

I hope it's possible to use a DC-DC convertor to get +5 V from +12 V. +3.3 V is closer to 5 V but likely the +12 V allows more current. All HDDs consume about 30 A, so I think it's better to convert +12 V to +5 V. I'm going to use something like this [DC DC converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PW3WHYC).

I believe that I need to connect the +12 V wire and thr GND wire from the PSU connector to the input of this converter and two output wires to the SATA connector - please see schema below.

Will it work? Is this schema correct in general (my concern is the way how the wires connect to the converter. Is it correct to connect the first pair GND/+12 V to the converter and another pair GND/+12 V to the SATA connector)? Is it safe?

[image]

Comment: It should be fine as long as your load's power consumption is lesser than the max output power of the PSU and DC-DC converter.

Comment: @ Prathik Prashanth Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no question *what* to convert here: the specs for the ATX Optional power supply specifies only 12 V power and *sensing* lines, from which you can't draw power. The HP-specific 10 pin version of that almost certainly doesn't provide much power over 3.3V over a long distance - that would be risky, as a 0.5V resistive drop due to cabling resistance is more sever at 3.3V than at 12V.

So, buck-convert your 12 V. (also, boosting 3.3V to 5V is usually technically more involved than going down in voltage).

Word of advise: 30A (at 5V: 150W!) is a lot, and these drives will all draw that at the same instant, namely on power on. make sure your power supply is potent enough to offer that amount of power!

I wouldn't even trust random amazon power supplies for private projects; for supplying hard drives in a server: certainly not. Get something from a name-brand power supply producer, through a *reputable* seller, like digikey, mouser, farnell, (tme), rs components…

Comment: Thank you. got it - buck convert 12V. I'm searching among converters that promise > 500 Watt (with high voltage). I selected most expensive converter from what is available here. My current configuration is two PSU: embedded in server (4x1200W) and external ATX that provides 5V. They have no common GND wire - therefore I try to power everything from HP embedded PSU. ATX is 850W and is capable to run 6 cages with 4 HDDs each. Likely server can spin up drives not simultaneously - the led lights blink sequentially - cage after cage.

Comment: When you say about reputable seller - do you mean PSU or buck-converter? Schema is correct(in general, regarding GND wires from SATA connector - one to converter, another directly to PSU)?

Comment: I see that converters with > 800 W support input voltage range higher then I need. Converters for 12V usually allow about 15A limit - therefore I think to divide cages into 2 sets and use 2 HP 10-pin connectors (each with its own buck-converter) Should I pay attention for frequency of buck converter?(I read that HDDs are sensitive to power quality )

Comment: Sorry - too many questions )) How reputable producers call such device - just buck converter? Maybe it's possible to extract good converter from ATX PSU like seasonic?

Comment: And last question :) What do you think is better: use two PSU with connected GND wire (internal and desktop PSU with native 5V) or use buck converter and power everything with 4x1200W internal HP PSU?

Comment: I searched in digikey site - I found only converters with about 3A max. https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/d/diodes/dc-dc-buck-converters

Comment: @VladNovakovsky this all sounds like what you really want is just another 230V -> 5V supply, separate from your main power supply.

Comment: This is what I try to avoid - Server has 4X1200W PSU-I want to use this capacity. And using only server PSU seems safer. I'm not in USA now and it's difficult to deliver something from sites oriented on USA market. In summary - I think you understand what I described in my schema and if you think it's incorrect then you would point on mistake. Likely you don't want to say "it's correct" because of some details (plus/minus of converter, pinout of SATA). Uncertainty with correctness of schema is the only reason why I'm hesitating. If it's correct in general is my concern

Comment: but you're **not** only using the server PSU. Instead, you need another PSU to convert the server's 12V to 5V. You only *lose* reliability that way.

Comment: Do you mean that it's better to use second ATX PSU (that provide +5V) to power cages with HDDs than to convert +12V from server's PSU to +5V using converter (and connect GND wire of server's and ATX PSU)? Or do you mean buck converter when saying "PSU"?

Comment: all these things are "power supply unit". A buck converter is one type.

Comment: @ Marcus Müller Unfortunately I'm still searching good buck converter but now I need to access data on HDD and I need fast temp solution. I have 3 identical ATX PSU. The schema of connecting master/slave ATX PSU is well known (connecting green and GND wire). But how to connect ATX to Proliant PSU - I do not see green wire connector on system board. Is it enough to connect GND wire say from 10-pin proliant connector to ATX PSU? For safety only - to avoid damage of server in case ATX PSU will have spike of voltage. I will turn ATX manually first.